# Flutter Sqflite database DatabaseException no such table Is Occur

Tags: database, flutter, dart, sqflite

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: MST_University (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM MST_University) sql 'SELECT * FROM MST_University' args []

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DataBaseHelper {
  static var _database;

  DataBaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DataBaseHelper instance = DataBaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      log("Database new is not creatred and retuned ");
      return _database;
    }
    // Call init Databasee method for New Database Creation
    log("new Database is create");
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    log("new dAta");
    String databasePath = join(appDocDir.path, 'pharmacy2.db');
    return await openDatabase(
      databasePath,
      version: 2,
    );
  }

  Future<void> copyPasteAssetFileToRoot() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    log("assets database is loading");
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "pharmacy2.db");

    if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(path) == FileSystemEntityType.notFound) {
      ByteData data =
          await rootBundle.load(join('assests/database', 'pharmacy2.db'));
      List<int> bytes =
          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
      await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    }
  }

  Future<void> getAllUniversity() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;

    var result = await db.query("MST_University");

    log(result.toString());
  }
}
```

I try a privet constructor for single instance and also load database from a assets

Answer (score 1):

- I cannot see where you call `copyPasteAssetFileToRoot`, so maybe never?
- `assests/database` looks very much like a typo.
- Even if that all is correct, the database you open has no such table.

Why don't you set a few breakpoints in your debugger and find out what steps work and which don't. Whether you path is set correctly and your file gets copied or not. Whether you open the correct file. Whether that file actually *has* such a table.